# How many players are required to play the Jackbox party games?

Tags: jackbox-party-pack, jackbox-party-pack-2

I’m looking at purchasing the Jackbox party games (a bundle containing the first three party packs) and am wondering, how many players are required to play? Is it possible for just two people to play, or is a larger group needed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The minimum varies from game-to-game. Generally each game is more fun with larger groups, but none of them require more than 3 players. (With the exception of Push The Button)

Aside from the original Fibbage and games from Jackbox Party Pack 1, each game allows extra players to join as audience members who can influence the game. (Usually up to 10,000)

---

#### [Fibbage](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/fibbage)

- Fibbage **(2-8 players)**

#### [The Jackbox Party Pack](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/packs/the-jackbox-party-pack-1)

- You Don't Know Jack 2015 **(1-4 players)**
- Fibbage XL **(2-8 players)**
- Drawful **(3-8 players)**
- Word Spud **(2-8 players)**
- Lie Swatter **(1-100 players)**

#### [Quiplash](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/quiplash)

- Quiplash **(3-8 players)**

#### [The Jackbox Party Pack 2](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/packs/the-jackbox-party-pack-2)

- Fibbage 2 **(2-8 players)**
- Earwax **(3-8 players)**
- Bidiots **(3-6 players)**
- Quiplash XL **(3-8 players)**
- Bomb Corp. **(1-4 players)**

#### [Drawful 2](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/drawful-2)

- Drawful 2 **(3-8 players)**

#### [The Jackbox Party Pack 3](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/packs/the-jackbox-party-pack-3)

- Quiplash 2 **(3-8 players)**
- Trivia Murder Party **(1-8 players)**
- Guesspionage **(2-8 players)**
- Tee K.O. **(3-8 players)**
- Fakin’ It **(3-6 players)**

#### [The Jackbox Party Pack 4](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/packs/the-jackbox-party-pack-4)

- Fibbage 3 & Fibbage: Enough About You **(2-8 players)**
- Survive the Internet **(3-8 players)**
- Monster Seeking Monster **(3-7 players)**
- Bracketeering **(3-16 players)**
- Civic Doodle **(3-8 players)**

#### [The Jackbox Party Pack 5](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/packs/the-jackbox-party-pack-5)

- You Don't Know Jack: Full Stream **(1-8 players)**
- Split the Room **(3-8 players)**
- Mad Verse City **(3-8 players)**
- Patently Stupid **(3-8 players)**
- Zeeple Dome **(1-6 players)**

#### [The Jackbox Party Pack 6](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/packs/the-jackbox-party-pack-6)

- Trivia Murder Party 2 **(1-8 players)**
- Dictionarium **(3-8 players)**
- Push The Button **(4-10 players)**
- Joke Boat **(3-8 players)**
- Role Models **(3-6 players)**

#### [The Jackbox Party Pack 7](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/packs/the-jackbox-party-pack-7)

- Quiplash 3 **(3-8 players)**
- The Devils and the Details **(3-8 players)**
- Champ’d Up **(3-8 players)**
- Talking Points **(3-8 players)**
- Blather ‘Round **(2-6 players)**

#### [The Jackbox Party Pack 8](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/packs/the-jackbox-party-pack-8)

- Drawful Animate **(3-10 players)**
- The Wheel of Enormous Proportions **(2-8 players)**
- Job Job **(3-10 players)**
- The Poll Mine **(2-10 players)**
- Weapons Drawn **(4-8 players)**

#### [The Jackbox Party Pack 9](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/packs/the-jackbox-party-pack-9)

- Fibbage 4 **(2-8 players)**
- Junktopia **(3-8 players)**
- Nonsensory **(3-8 players)**
- Roomerang **(4-9 players)**
- Quixort **(2-10 players)**

#### [The Jackbox Party Pack 10](https://www.jackboxgames.com/games/packs/the-jackbox-party-pack-10)

- Fixy Text **(3-8 players)**
- Tee K.O. 2 **(3-8 players)**
- DodoReMi **(1-9 players)**
- Time Jinx **(1-8 players)**
- Hypnotorious **(4-8 players)**

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the game. For example, Jackbox Party Pack 1 contains 5 games.

- You Don't Know Jack 2015 (1-4 players)
- Fibbage XL (2-8 players)
- Drawful (3-8 players)
- Word Spud (2-8 players)
- Lie Swatter (1-100 players)

More details can be found on the [jackbox website](https://jackboxgames.com/games/).